# Compiling applications with mono

Tags: c#, linux, compilation, mono

I have a few questions about Mono:

1) Is there a way to compile application for Linux without installation of Xamarin Studio?
For example i have my helloworld.cs, i use dmcs to compile it into exe. Is there another compiler or flag to compile app for linux?

2) I need to statically link Mono runtime to run on the computer without Mono installed.
There is mkbundle command but it is a very difficult process to make it work on Windows. And static linking does not work on Windows.

And besides, I need to automate these processes =/

P.S. As I said, I'm working on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn't matter if you compile your code with the Microsoft or Mono compiler, the resulting assembly should work on all platforms (as long as you don't use any platform-specific code of course).

You can take an assembly compiled with the MS compiler and run it on Linux/Mac with Mono, or compile on Mono and run it on Windows/.NET.

2) Problems with mkbundle should probably be filed as a bug on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com